# Cannot get value from application.yml in ApplicationRunner

Tags: spring-boot

I've added my tiny initialization class in the same package with Spring Boot application (the main) class. (I want to perform some database initialization after all tables are created by Hibernate's `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property.) But the initialization class is not get populated with properties from `application.yml`.

**Initialization class:**

```
@Component
public class LocalInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {
    @Value("${local.initialize}")
    private String[] localInitialize;

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(localInitialize));
    }
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
local.initialize:
  - test-string1
  - test-string2
```

**error:**

```
...
Hibernate: drop table if exists t_worker cascade
Hibernate: drop sequence if exists hibernate_sequence
2019-05-22 17:06:45.530  INFO 16680 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-05-22 17:06:45.541  INFO 16680 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-05-22 17:06:45.542  INFO 16680 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-05-22 17:06:45.579  INFO 16680 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-05-22 17:06:45.600 ERROR 16680 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'localInitializer': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.initialize' in value "${local.initialize}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at ua.aval.cards.dictionary.CardsDictionaryApp.main(CardsDictionaryApp.java:17) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.initialize' in value "${local.initialize}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:839) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1083) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:55405', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: is there a reason you don't use a ```@ConfigurationProperties``` component? You have an application.yaml file so...

Answer (score 0):

```
local.initialize:
  test-string1, 
  test-string2
```

should work. note: use a ',' and leave out the '-' char

---

Remark:

When using a ConfigurationProperties Component like

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprops")
public class MyProperties {

  private String[] initialize;

  public String[] getInitialize() {
    return initialize;
  }

  public void setInitialize(String[] initialize) {
    this.initialize = initialize;
  }
}
```

then this works

```
@Component
public class LocalInitializer implements CommandLineRunner{
  private final MyProperties myprops;

  @Value("${local.initialize:failed}")
  private String[] localInitialize;



  public LocalInitializer(MyProperties myprops) {
    this.myprops = myprops;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(localInitialize));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myprops.getInitialize()));
  }

}
```

in combination with application.yaml

```
local.initialize:
  test-string1, 
  test-string2

myprops:
  initialize:
  - this is
  - a bit
  - strange
```

prints out

```
[test-string1, test-string2]
[this is, a bit, strange]
```